# Does NHaml have a content_for ability for layouts?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhaml

I am currently starting a project utilizing ASP.NET MVC and would like to use NHaml as my view engine as I love Haml from Rails/Merb. The main issue I face is the laying out of my pages. In Webforms, I would place a ContentPlaceHolder in the head so that other pages can have specific CSS and JavaScript files.

In Rails, this is done utilizing yield and content_for

File: application.haml

```
%html
  %head
    - yield :style
```

File: page.haml

```
- content_for :style do 
  / specific styles for this page
```

In NHaml, I can do this with partials, however any partials are global for the entire controller folder.

File: application.haml

```
!!!
%html{xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"}
  %head
    _ Style
```

File: _Style.haml

```
%link{src="http://www.thescore.com/css/style.css?version=1.1" type="text/css"}
```

Does anyone know of a way to get NHaml to work in the Rails scenario?

Answer (score 2):

Use the ^ evaluator in the master page, and set it's value in each of the layouts(content pages).

See [NHaml Samples](http://code.google.com/p/nhaml/source/browse/tags/1.4.0/src/Samples/NHaml.Samples.Mvc/) from it's source on [Google Code](http://code.google.com).

Answer (score 0):

The "content placeholders" are not yet supported.
But there is a [request for that](http://code.google.com/p/nhaml/issues/detail?id=5#c10).

You can vote [for it too](http://nhaml.uservoice.com/pages/18694-general/suggestions/276848-multiple-content-placeholders)

BUT this is how I provided per-page content in NHAML:
http://dnagir.blogspot.com/2009/07/nhaml-scripts-and-styles-code-block.html